# Magento2 doesn't load images and css

Tags: javascript, css, magento, http-status-code-404, magento2

I have downloaded and installed Magento 2 but I'm getting 404 error for scripts and css. An example of my image path is: http://www.arredomobilionline.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/it_IT/images/logo.svg

I've already tried this solution:

> Open up app/etc/di.xml and find the virtualType
>   name="developerMaterialization" section. In that section you'll find
>   an item name="view_preprocessed" that needs to be modified or deleted.
>   You can modify it by changing the contents from
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink to
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

inside my deafult di.xml file as default there's:

```
    <virtualType name="developerMaterialization" type="Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Factory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="strategiesList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
            <item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

I tried to delete the first symlink part or change it into "copy" but it's not working.
I've also set 777 permission to every file.

Answer (score 4):

Use below command for import sample data and load css/js
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

 php bin/magento indexer:reindex

 php bin/magento cache:flush`

and check affected folder `pub\static\`

Answer (score 1):

I think after installing composer, you should try

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

If you are going to develop a theme this will be needed to run on every change or you need to find some other solution

Answer (score 0):

This One Worked for Me. use this in Terminal "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy"

Step 1 : In CMD Open your root directory using cd command

Step 2 : "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" - run this Command

then,Check Your pub/static folder, CSS and Js files will be available there

Answer (score 0):

The following steps are worked for me

You need delete files from public/static/frontend and also var/cache

step 1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

For more information visit this blog

https://samumaretiya.wordpress.com/2016/01/09/javascript-magento-2-not-loading-css-and-js/

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following commands to eliminate 404 error for scripts and css:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```